# conda update conda won't work

Tags: python, conda

I would like to update conda to get the later version of python and its extensions but it keeps telling me this :

```
(base) C:\Users\pierr>conda update conda
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.2
  latest version: 4.5.4

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda



# All requested packages already installed.


(base) C:\Users\pierr>conda update -n base conda
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.2
  latest version: 4.5.4

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda



# All requested packages already installed.
```

Any help here please ?

Comment: Could you share your environment.yml file by typing the following at the terminal ' conda env export > pierre.yml'

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some documentation issue here. Apparently, 'conda update -n base conda' does not work any longer.
It seems that no one has fixed the documentation.

---

> conda update --all

seems to work for me.